# Botão para fechar modal não funciona

Tags: react, typescript, modal, react-hooks

Olá, estou com um problema para fazer o botão do meu modal fechar, ele abre através do `header` da aplicação normalmente.

Estou usando ReactJS 16.8 + TypeScript 4.0.3.

```js
// Header/index.tsx
import ContactForm from '../Contact';

import { Container, Contact } from './styles';

const Header: React.FC = () => {
  const [isContactVisible, setIsContactVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Container>          
      <Contact onClick={() => setIsContactVisible(true)}>
        {isContactVisible ? (
          <ContactForm onClose={() => setIsContactVisible(false)} />
        ) : null}
        Contact
      </Contact>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

O código do Modal:

```js
// Modal//
import exitButton from '../../assets/exitButton.svg';

import { Container, Content } from './styles';

type Props = {
  onClose: any;
};

const Contact: React.FC<Props> = ({ onClose = () => {} }) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Content>
        <button type="button" onClick={onClose}>
          {console.log('Fechou! ', onClose)}
          <img src={exitButton} alt="Exit contact" />
        </button>
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

Saída do console ao clicar, **por uma vez**, no botão do `header`, **e não no de sair**:

[image: Captura de tela de 2020-11-28 21-52-08.png]

O botão para sair do modal não funciona e não sai nada dele no console. Como fazer para ele funcionar? Agradeço desde já.

P.S.: Sei que existe a biblioteca react-modal, mas gostaria de fazer sem ela, a não ser que não tenha saída neste caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de 1 dia e meio olhando para o código e pesquisando no Google, encontrei o erro:

No `header/index.tsx` eu estava colocando a função dentro do botão, quando a tela renderizava a função renderizava junto e tratava o modal como um botão.

Antes:

```js
<Contact onClick={() => setIsContactVisible(true)}>
  {isContactVisible ? (
    <ContactForm onClose={() => setIsContactVisible(false)} />
  ) : null}
  Contact
</Contact>
```

Depois:

```js
<Contact onClick={() => setIsContactVisible(true)}>Contact</Contact>
{isContactVisible ? (
  <ContactForm onClose={() => setIsContactVisible(false)} />
) : null}
```